# i want to see server log file from browser in rails app button click

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, terminal

i have a make a deployment app , by clicking deployment button it deployed, now i want to see the log file like terminal show in browser

i try to read the log file using file read but when i start to read my application stop with this

```
Rendering deployments/show_log.html.erb within layouts/application
/home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:350: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00007f46a87f1000
ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0123 p:---- s:0827 e:000826 CFUNC  :escapeHTML
c:0122 p:0036 s:0822 e:000821 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:350
c:0121 p:0012 s:0814 e:000812 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:216
c:0120 p:0016 s:0808 e:000807 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/buffers.rb:29
c:0119 p:0022 s:0803 e:000802 METHOD /home/syftet/development/trusteeze-saas/app/views/deployments/show_log.html.erb:2 [FINISH]
c:0118 p:---- s:0797 e:000796 CFUNC  :public_send
c:0117 p:0042 s:0790 e:000789 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:244
c:0116 p:0025 s:0776 e:000775 BLOCK  /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/template.rb:157
c:0115 p:0034 s:0773 e:000772 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208
c:0114 p:0024 s:0767 e:000766 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/template.rb:361
c:0113 p:0021 s:0762 e:000761 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/template.rb:155
c:0112 p:0013 s:0751 e:000750 BLOCK  /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:65
c:0111 p:0010 s:0748 e:000747 BLOCK  /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206
c:0110 p:0022 s:0745 e:000744 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24
c:0109 p:0023 s:0737 e:000736 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206
c:0108 p:0033 s:0731 e:000730 BLOCK  /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:60
c:0107 p:0011 s:0727 e:000724 BLOCK  /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:75
c:0106 p:0010 s:0722 e:000721 BLOCK  /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206
c:0105 p:0022 s:0719 e:000718 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24
c:0104 p:0023 s:0711 e:000710 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206
c:0103 p:0050 s:0705 e:000704 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:74
c:0102 p:0012 s:0695 e:000694 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59
c:0101 p:0048 s:0687 e:000686 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:11
c:0100 p:0020 s:0680 e:000679 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:61
c:0099 p:0023 s:0674 e:000673 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:29
c:0098 p:0009 s:0668 e:000667 BLOCK  /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:117
c:0097 p:0089 s:0664 e:000663 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:270
c:0096 p:0051 s:0656 e:000655 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:116
c:0095 p:0044 s:0646 e:000645 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:216
c:0094 p:0015 s:0641 e:000640 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionview-7.0.5/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103
c:0093 p:0010 s:0636 e:000635 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:158
c:0092 p:0015 s:0631 e:000630 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141
c:0091 p:0018 s:0626 e:000625 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:27
c:0090 p:0033 s:0618 e:000617 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:139
c:0089 p:0010 s:0613 e:000612 BLOCK  /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22
c:0088 p:0028 s:0610 e:000609 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/benchmark.rb:308
c:0087 p:0009 s:0605 e:000603 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14
c:0086 p:0013 s:0599 e:000598 BLOCK  /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22
c:0085 p:0002 s:0596 e:000595 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:91
c:0084 p:0066 s:0592 e:000591 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:34
c:0083 p:0008 s:0585 e:000583 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:21
c:0082 p:0021 s:0578 e:000577 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:35
c:0081 p:0020 s:0573 e:000572 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:7
c:0080 p:0011 s:0566 e:000565 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:215
c:0079 p:0022 s:0560 e:000559 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:165
c:0078 p:0009 s:0555 e:000554 BLOCK  /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:234
c:0077 p:0048 s:0552 E:002550 BLOCK  /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118
c:0076 p:0013 s:0542 E:002590 METHOD /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actiontext-7.0.5/lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20
c:0075 p:0021 s:0536 E:0025d0 BLOCK  /home/syftet/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actiontext-7.0.5/lib/action_text/engine.rb:69 [FINISH]
c:0074 p:---- s:0531 e:000530 CFUNC  :instance_exec
```

Comment: Please share the code you use to read and render that page.